# Como alterar linha no arquivo de texto em C#?

Tags: c#, txt, replace

Atualmente informo na variável `stringantiga` o valor exato para encontrar e substitui-la.

Existe alguma maneira de substituir pelo número da linha ao invés do valor exato de `stringantiga`?

```
string arquivo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Caminho"].ToString();
string stringbusca = "MaxChannelInUse";
string stringantiga = "MaxChannelInUse=80";
string stringnova = "MaxChannelInUse=90000";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(arquivo);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string s = sr.ReadLine();
    if (s.IndexOf(stringbusca) > -1)
    {
        s = s.Replace(stringantiga, stringnova);
    }
    sb.AppendLine(s);
}
sr.Close();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(arquivo);
sw.Write(sb);

sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Você pode simplesmente ler todo o arquivo usando o método [**`File.ReadAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx), alterar a linha e depois escrever no arquivo usando o método [**`File.WriteAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var arquivo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Caminho"].ToString();
var linhas = File.ReadAllLines(arquivo);

arquivo[0] = "Novo conteúdo"; // Editar a primeira linha

File.WriteAllLines(arquivo, linhas);
```

Comment: Por exemplo, se por acaso alguma pessoa entrar no meu arquivo de texto e excluir uma das linhas. Existe alguma outra maneira de encontrar aquele valor especifico, no meu exemplo (stringantiga= "MaxChannelInUse") ?

Comment: @GabrielSant'Ana Com certeza não.